# Get state for child components connected to redux with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test a redux connected component. The component changes its properties on a resize event.

I want to mount my DatePicker component with enzyme, dispatch a resize event, and test that my DatePicker's prop value `IS_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT === true` and because of this, my DatePicker's state has changed as well.

However I cannot access the state of my DatePicker because enzyme does not let you access the state if the wrapper component is not the root:

```
console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').state())
// ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on the root
```

I've tried wrapping the connected DatePicker in a Provider as the docs suggest, as well as mounting it directly but passing store as a prop. Neither of these methods seem to allow me to refer to DatePicker as the root component and thus neither of these methods allow me to get the state of my component.

Here are my attempts:
The output of these console logs is here: https://gist.github.com/gecko25/56fb14154585a2d06697c399685c9111

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureDataStore from '%SRC%/store/configure';
import { windowResize } from '%CONSTANTS%/store/actions';
import  ConnectedDatePicker, { DatePicker }  from './DatePicker';

const DESKTOP = 1025;

describe('calendar open and closes', () => {

    test('connected attempt #1', ()=>{

        const store = configureDataStore();

        const options = {
          context: { store },
          childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.object }
        }

        const wrapper = mount(<ConnectedDatePicker store={store}/>)

        store.dispatch(windowResize(DESKTOP));

        console.log('state-->', wrapper.state()) // {}
        console.log('props-->', wrapper.props()) // Doesn't include all my component specific props
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').props()) // Prints all props as expected
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').state()) // Error

        console.log('--------------------------')

    })

    test('connected attempt #2', () => {

        const store = configureDataStore();

        const options = {
          context: { store },
          childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.object }
        }

        const wrapper = mount(<ConnectedDatePicker/>, options)

        store.dispatch(windowResize(DESKTOP));


        console.log('state-->', wrapper.state()) // {}
        console.log('props-->', wrapper.props()) // Doesn't include all my component specific props
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').props()) // Prints all props as expected
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').state()) // Error

    });

    test('connected attempt #3', () => {

        const store = configureDataStore();

        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedDatePicker/></Provider>)

        store.dispatch(windowResize(DESKTOP));

        console.log('state-->', wrapper.state()) // null
        console.log('props-->', wrapper.props()); // Doesn't include all my component specific props
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').props()) // Prints all props as expected
        console.log(wrapper.find('DatePicker').state()) // Error
        console.log('--------------------------')

    });
});
```

Comment: Usually, it's recommended to test undecorated component by mocking props coming from Redux manually and test your reducers separately. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/98

Answer (score 6):

`wrapper.find('DatePicker').instance().state` should work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as follows:

1. Make sure your `DatePicker`:

   ```
   export class DatePicker... // without export it would not work in your test file
   export default connect(...)(DatePicker);
   ```
2. Several ways you can get the state:

   1. If you do:

      ```
      const wrapper = shallow(<connectedDatePicker {...props} />)
      ```

      you need to dive twice to DatePicker to get the state:

      ```
      expect(wrapper.dive().dive().state()).toEqual({...})
      ```
   2. If you do:

      ```
      const wrapper = shallow(<DatePicker {...props} />);
      ```

      you do not need dive to get the state.

      ```
      expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({...})
      ```

**HERE IS WHAT AN AIRBNB Developer suggested me to do:**
To get the wrapper state, `wrapper.instance().state` is not suggested,
you'd better use `wrapper.state()`

Comment: in a the shallow is wrapping the connectedComponent

Comment: in b the shallow is wrapping the component it self

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
let component = shallow(<ConnectedDatePicker store={store}/>).dive().dive();
it("The description", () => {
     expect(component.state('StateName')).toEqual('something');
});
```